# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment when ignite native persistence is on

Tags: java, ignite

I try to put Apache Arrow vector in Ignite, this is working fine when I turn off native persistence, but after I turn on native persistence, JVM is crashed every time.
I create IntVector first then put it in Ignite:

```
RootAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator(Long.MAX_VALUE);
IntVector intVector = new IntVector("int", allocator);
intVector.setSafe(0, 1);
igniteCache.put("key", intVector);
```

I can get "key" at first run, after I turn on native persistence and comment out above codes, JVM is crashed when calling

```
IntVector intVector = (IntVector) igniteCache.get("key");    //CRASHED HERE!!!
intVector.get(0);
```

with following error(only some of them):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f778362098d, pid=30450, tid=0x00007f7782a28700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_271-b09) (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.271-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xaa898d]  Unsafe_GetNativeByte+0xad
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f777c00c800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=30451, stack(0x00007f7782929000,0x00007f7782a29000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00007f96825662d8

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f777c00c800, RBX=0x00007f777c00c800, RCX=0x00000005cc456068, RDX=0x00007f7783f9f340
RSP=0x00007f7782a27760, RBP=0x00007f7782a27790, RSI=0x0000000000000001, RDI=0x0000000000000010
R8 =0x00007f777c00c800, R9 =0x0000000000000004, R10=0x00007f776d6f2cb8, R11=0x00007f776d6f2c98
R12=0x00007f96825662d8, R13=0x00007f7782a277f8, R14=0x00007f7782a27870, R15=0x00007f7783b4e2ec
RIP=0x00007f778362098d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f7782a27760)
0x00007f7782a27760:   00000007c000e158 00007f776c47b130
0x00007f7782a27770:   0000000000000000 00007f7782a277f8
0x00007f7782a27780:   00007f7782a27870 00007f777c00c800
0x00007f7782a27790:   00007f7782a277e0 00007f776d6f2d28
0x00007f7782a277a0:   00000005cc456068 00007f747f23c1e0
0x00007f7782a277b0:   00007f7782a27800 00000000000000b6
0x00007f7782a277c0:   0000000000000000 00007f747f23d03e
0x00007f7782a277d0:   00007f7782a27870 00007f777c00c800
0x00007f7782a277e0:   00007f7782a27850 00007f776d0079c0
0x00007f7782a277f0:   00007f776d0079c0 00007f96825662d8
0x00007f7782a27800:   000000071e23bbd0 00000005cc456068
0x00007f7782a27810:   00007f7782a27810 00007f747f23d03e
0x00007f7782a27820:   00007f7782a27870 00007f747f2ec4e0
0x00007f7782a27830:   0000000000000000 00007f747f23d068
0x00007f7782a27840:   00007f7782a277f8 00007f7782a27860
0x00007f7782a27850:   00007f7782a278b8 00007f776d0079c0
0x00007f7782a27860:   0000000000000000 00007f776d023f9f
0x00007f7782a27870:   000000071e23bbd0 00007f7782a27878
0x00007f7782a27880:   00007f74807265aa 00007f7782a278e8
0x00007f7782a27890:   00007f748072d228 0000000000000000
0x00007f7782a278a0:   00007f7480726608 00007f7782a27860
0x00007f7782a278b0:   00007f7782a278e0 00007f7782a27930
0x00007f7782a278c0:   00007f776d007d00 0000000000000000
0x00007f7782a278d0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f7782a278e0:   0000000000000000 000000071b339de8
0x00007f7782a278f0:   00007f7782a278f0 00007f748071d730
0x00007f7782a27900:   00007f7782a27948 00007f747f239028
0x00007f7782a27910:   0000000000000000 00007f748071d778
0x00007f7782a27920:   00007f7782a278e0 00007f7782a27940
0x00007f7782a27930:   00007f7782a27998 00007f776d007d00
0x00007f7782a27940:   0000000000000000 000000071b339de8
0x00007f7782a27950:   00000005cc55ec98 00007f7782a27958 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f778362098d)
0x00007f778362096d:   ff 48 8d 05 73 6f 4f 00 c7 83 70 02 00 00 06 00
0x00007f778362097d:   00 00 8b 38 e8 12 61 75 ff c6 80 94 02 00 00 01
0x00007f778362098d:   45 0f b6 34 24 c6 80 94 02 00 00 00 4c 8b 63 48
0x00007f778362099d:   49 8b 44 24 10 4d 8b 6c 24 08 48 83 38 00 74 1c 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f777c00c800 is a thread
RBX=0x00007f777c00c800 is a thread
RCX=0x00000005cc456068 is an oop
sun.misc.Unsafe 
 - klass: 'sun/misc/Unsafe'
RDX=0x00007f7783f9f340: <offset 0x1e340> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 at 0x00007f7783f81000
RSP=0x00007f7782a27760 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f777c00c800
RBP=0x00007f7782a27790 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f777c00c800
RSI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f777c00c800 is a thread
R9 =0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f776d6f2cb8 is at entry_point+56 in (nmethod*)0x00007f776d6f2b10
R11=0x00007f776d6f2c98 is at entry_point+24 in (nmethod*)0x00007f776d6f2b10
R12=0x00007f96825662d8 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007f7782a277f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f777c00c800
R14=0x00007f7782a27870 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f777c00c800
R15=0x00007f7783b4e2ec: <offset 0xfd62ec> in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f7782b78000


Stack: [0x00007f7782929000,0x00007f7782a29000],  sp=0x00007f7782a27760,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xaa898d]  Unsafe_GetNativeByte+0xad
J 2166  sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte(J)B (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f776d6f2d28 [0x00007f776d6f2c80+0xa8]
j  org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.getByte(J)B+14
j  org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseFixedWidthVector.isSet(I)I+10
j  org.apache.arrow.vector.IntVector.get(I)I+8
j  org.apache.ignite.examples.test.MainApplication.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+99
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x68c2ba]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0xe1a
V  [libjvm.so+0x6d8700]  jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) [clone .isra.98] [clone .constprop.118]+0x1f0
V  [libjvm.so+0x6da9fb]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x15b
C  [libjli.so+0x889c]  JavaMain+0xa3c
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x9609]  start_thread+0xd9

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2166  sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte(J)B (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f776d6f2cb8 [0x00007f776d6f2c80+0x38]
j  org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.getByte(J)B+14
j  org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseFixedWidthVector.isSet(I)I+10
j  org.apache.arrow.vector.IntVector.get(I)I+8
j  org.apache.ignite.examples.test.MainApplication.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+99
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

```
Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f772c097000 JavaThread "mgmt-#73" [_thread_blocked, id=30583, stack(0x00007f747f439000,0x00007f747f53a000)]
  0x00007f76b000d000 JavaThread "checkpoint-runner-#72" [_thread_blocked, id=30582, stack(0x00007f747f53a000,0x00007f747f63b000)]
  0x00007f76b000b000 JavaThread "checkpoint-runner-#71" [_thread_blocked, id=30581, stack(0x00007f747f63b000,0x00007f747f73c000)]
  0x00007f76b0009000 JavaThread "checkpoint-runner-#70" [_thread_blocked, id=30580, stack(0x00007f747f73c000,0x00007f747f83d000)]
  0x00007f76b0006800 JavaThread "checkpoint-runner-#69" [_thread_blocked, id=30579, stack(0x00007f747f83d000,0x00007f747f93e000)]
  0x00007f772c072800 JavaThread "db-checkpoint-thread-#68" [_thread_in_native, id=30578, stack(0x00007f747f93e000,0x00007f747fa3f000)]

....

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 3.808 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 383488K, used 365568K [0x0000000719700000, 0x000000073b300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 365568K, 100% used [0x0000000719700000,0x000000072fc00000,0x000000072fc00000)
  from space 17920K, 0% used [0x000000073a180000,0x000000073a180000,0x000000073b300000)
  to   space 20992K, 0% used [0x0000000738a00000,0x0000000738a00000,0x0000000739e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 338944K, used 24142K [0x00000005cc400000, 0x00000005e0f00000, 0x0000000719700000)
  object space 338944K, 7% used [0x00000005cc400000,0x00000005cdb939b8,0x00000005e0f00000)
 Metaspace       used 41397K, capacity 43002K, committed 43304K, reserved 1087488K
  class space    used 4722K, capacity 5078K, committed 5160K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 3.822 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 523776K, used 20987K [0x0000000719700000, 0x000000073c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 502784K, 0% used [0x0000000719700000,0x0000000719700000,0x0000000738200000)
  from space 20992K, 99% used [0x0000000738a00000,0x0000000739e7ee08,0x0000000739e80000)
  to   space 31744K, 0% used [0x000000073a100000,0x000000073a100000,0x000000073c000000)
 ParOldGen       total 338944K, used 32466K [0x00000005cc400000, 0x00000005e0f00000, 0x0000000719700000)
  object space 338944K, 9% used [0x00000005cc400000,0x00000005ce3b4800,0x00000005e0f00000)
 Metaspace       used 41397K, capacity 43002K, committed 43304K, reserved 1087488K
  class space    used 4722K, capacity 5078K, committed 5160K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 5.314 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776d7db69c method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.curIdx()I @ 5
Event: 5.315 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f776ddc6474 method=jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ByteVector.putInt(I)Ljdk/internal/org/objectweb/asm/ByteVector; @ 13
Event: 5.315 Thread 0x00007f777e4c7000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f776d9d9da8 method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;Z)Z @ 40
Event: 5.316 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776d7db69c method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.curIdx()I @ 5
Event: 5.316 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776d7db69c method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.curIdx()I @ 5
Event: 5.317 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776d718734 method=java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 13
Event: 5.322 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776d7db69c method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.curIdx()I @ 5
Event: 5.324 Thread 0x00007f777e4c7000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f776d412e68 method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridCompoundFuture.futuresCountNoLock()I @ 25
Event: 5.325 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776d7dbadc method=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.curIdx()I @ 5
Event: 5.330 Thread 0x00007f777c00c800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f776dd30be0 method=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl.acquirePage(IJLorg/apache/ignite/internal/metric/IoStatisticsHolder;ZLjava/util/concurrent

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events
....
```

It's been torturing me for days, any hint would be helpful, thanks

**simple code to reproduce this problem**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("example-ignite.xml")) {
            IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");
            //put string in cache at 1st run then comment it out at 2nd run to test native persistence
            cache.put(0, "222"); //will not crash if I comment out this line at 2nd run.
            System.out.println(cache.get(0));

            //put arrow vector in cache at 1st run then comment it out at 2nd run to test native persistence
            RootAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator();
            IntVector vector = new IntVector("int", allocator);
            vector.allocateNew();
            vector.setSafe(0, 111);
            vector.setValueCount(1);
            cache.put(1, vector);   //crashed if I comment out this line at 2nd run.
            System.out.println(cache.get(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Native persistence setting:**

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <!--                <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{128 * 1024 * 1024}"/>-->
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

**Dependency**

```
<properties>
        <ignite.version>2.9.1</ignite.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.27.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
            <artifactId>arrow-vector</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.arrow.gandiva</groupId>
            <artifactId>arrow-gandiva</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
            <artifactId>arrow-memory-netty</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: What versions of Ignite & Arrow do you use? I wasn't able to reproduce hurriedly.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm using Ignite 2.9.1 and Arrow 4.0, it only happened when I turn on native persistence

Comment: @VladimirPligin What is most important to reproduce this problem is: If I call put first, then call get, there is no problem even with native persistence on. If I don't execute put logic but call get directly, JVM will crash.

Comment: @VladimirPligin updated simple code to reproduce this problem, please pay attention to the comments in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Arrow utilizes a pretty similar idea of Java off-heap storage as Apache Ignite does. For Apache Arrow it means that objects like `IntVector` don't actually store data in their on-heap layout. They just store a reference to a buffer containing an off-heap `address` of a physical representation. Technically it's a `long` offset pointing to a chunk of memory within JVM address space.

When you restart your JVM, address space changes. But in your Apache Ignite native persistence there's a record holding an old pointer. It leads to a `SIGSEGV` because it's not in the JVM address anymore (in fact it doesn't even exist after a restart).

You could use Apache Arrow [serialization](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/ipc.html) machinery to store data permanently in Apache Ignite or even somewhere else. But in fact after that you're going to lose Apache Arrow preciousness as a fast in-memory columnar store. It was initially designed to share off-heap data across multiple data-processing solutions.

Therefore I believe that technically it could be possible to leverage Apache Ignite [binary](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/binary-marshaller) storage format. In that case a custom [BinarySerializer](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/binary/BinarySerializer.html) should be implemented. After that it would be possible to use it with the Apache Arrow vector classes.

```xml
<property name="binaryConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
        <property name="typeConfigurations">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryTypeConfiguration">
                    <property name="typeName" value="org.apache.arrow.vector.*"/>
                    <property name="serializer" ref="customSerializer"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for your time and patience